# What does "removed" suggest in my reputation history?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

I recently lost 2 reputation points from my math.stackexchange account with the word "removed" written next to it. Also next to removed was "break map components down to direct sums" which I assume was some question asked on the site at some point.

I understand what "user was removed" is but what is this "removed"? I thought it might be due to removing the question "break map components down to direct sums" but I have no recollection of either asking or answering a question of this title.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to click on the word *removed*? Is some tooltip shown when you hover over it? A possible explanation could be that a post where you made a suggested edit was removed: [What is the reason for this change of reputation?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25137)

Comment: And based on your description, it really seems to be the case here: http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/527943

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you! I can't click on the word removed. I think I don't have enough reputation to do so. Thank you for finding that suggested edit link.

Comment: Just to clarify: I was not claiming that it is possible to click on it, I was asking. (I do not see the -2 change in your reputation tab, so I can't try it myself.) After my comments, can your question be considered duplicate of the one I linked above?

Comment: Okay. Yes, now it is a duplicate. Should I delete it or will you mark it as duplicate?

Comment: Perhaps it is worth keeping. [Duplicates might be useful](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9586/avoiding-duplicates/9588#9588). If somebody else has similar problem, depending on search terms they might be able to find your question or the other one. Duplicates with good titles also might be useful in populating lists of related questions and list of questions shown when user is asking a question.

Comment: The title of the removed question becomes a link when one has the required privileges to see the deleted question, that is, when one has 10k rep (or is a moderator). I think for one's own questions, which one can see after deletion regardless of reputation, it's also a link before one has reached 10k, but I don't know that for sure.  (cc @MartinSleziak)